How does $\log(y)=C+t$ become $y = C e^{t}$?
I came across this transformation :
$$\begin{align}
\log(y) &= C + t \tag{1} \\[4pt]
y &= C e^{t} \tag{2}
\end{align}$$
How was the first step simplified into the second?

My hint is that the author is using $C$ to just mean "some" constant. It would be good to show what your approach was to this problem

We consider the C in first expression to be a value that can be written as $\ln k$. So $$\ln y=t+\ln k \implies \ln y -\ln k=t \implies \ln\frac{y}{k}=t \implies \frac{y}{k}=e^t \implies y=ke^t$$

@Gwen: You should write it as an answer.

This is abuse of notation. $C$ here means "some constant function" so $e^C$ is also written as $C$. This should not be encouraged because it would not work if multiple constants are required

Let the first $C$ in the first expression be expressed as $\ln k$, as range of $\ln k \in \mathbb{R}$.
So $$\ln y=t+\ln k \implies \ln y-\ln k=t \\\implies \ln \bigg(\frac{y}{k}\bigg)=t \implies \frac{y}{k} = e^t \implies y=ke^t$$
